# How to create and display output in a second form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a second form on the fly & display results from variables in the main form to a label on the second form. Please how do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sense there are several questions here.

How to open a new form: in some method of `Form1`, add the following code:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

How to pass values from `Form1` to `Form2`: pass them when you call the `Form2` constructor:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(String value, Boolean isDone);
```

And the `Form2` constructor should look like:

```
public Form2(String form1Value, Boolean form1IsDone) {
    label1.Text = form1Value;
    label2.Text = form1IsDone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
var form = new Form
{
    Owner = this
};
var label = new Label
{
    Text = "Hello"
};
form.Controls.Add(label);
form.Show();
```

Of course you have to do a little more work for layout, but this is just a sample "how it goes".

Comment: ShowDialog is modal, which means that you must close the form, before doing anything else. Show isn't, which means that you can use both forms at the same time and change the focus between the two deliberately. But in both cases you should pass the first form as a parameter which specifies the owner of the form.  secondForm.Show(firstForm);. This ensures that the second form is always on top of the first and that it cannot disappear behind the first, especially if it is smaller than the first.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Better is to set the owner on initializing. I forgot it and corrected it.

Comment: You are setting the owner of the label. I am talking about setting the owner of the newly created form.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: You're so right, and I'm so blind. :-) I've coreccted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Form newForm = new Form();
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ReadOnly = true;
tb.Multiline = true;
tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

tb.Text = "One and" + Environment.NewLine + "two lines of text";

newForm.Controls.Add(tb);
newForm.ShowDialog();
```

Replace `TextBox` with `Label` or whatever you like.
But if you don't need to dynamically generate the layout of the new form everytime you should really create a new Form in the Visual Studio designer and open that form, passing the content properties to that form.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.SetContent("One and" + Environment.NewLine + "two lines of text");
form2.ShowDialog();
```

where `SetContent` is a public method you create in the `Form2` class. The `SetContent` method should text the text of appropriate labels etc.

Comment: Yes. You could also pass the content and other info to the form constructor and let the form decide how to build up itself dynamically, depending on the info.